# shell script remove duplicate column from output

Tags: shell, awk

Shell script only !

I have the following output of 2 columns.
I would like to eliminate the duplicates in the col 2.

Example output now:

```
1    Sample1
1    Sample2
1    Sample3
2    Sample1
2    Sample2
2    Sample3
3    Sample1
3    Sample4
```

Desired output:

```
1    Sample1
1    Sample2
1    Sample3
3    Sample4
```

Thank you !

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself. Please take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

This compact one-liner will give you that output:

```
awk '!a[$2]++' input
```

Answer (score 0):

You could harness [`uniq`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/uniq) for this task if it is acceptable to have output sorted lexicographically by 2nd item, as is case with your example. Let `file.txt` content be

```
1    Sample1
1    Sample2
1    Sample3
2    Sample1
2    Sample2
2    Sample3
3    Sample1
3    Sample4
```

then

```
sort -k2 -u file.txt
```

output

```
1    Sample1
1    Sample2
1    Sample3
3    Sample4
```

Explanation: `-k2` means do use 2nd field, `-u` does only print unique lines.